# How can I convert a byte array to a double in python?

Tags: java, python, double, byte

I am using Java to convert a double into a byte array. Like this:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(double value) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[8];
    ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).putDouble(value);
    return bytes;
}
```

Now, I would like to convert this byte array back into a double. In Java I would do it like this:

```
public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Now, how can I write the `toDouble()` method in Python?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Python has the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to convert bytes back to `float` values:

```
import struct

value = struct.unpack('d', bytes)[0]
```

Here `'d'` signifies that a double value is expected (in native endianess, as 8 bytes). See the module documentation for more options, including specifying endianess.

Another option is to turn your `bytes` value into an [`array` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html); you'd use this is if you had a homogenous sequence of doubles:

```
import array

doubles_sequence = array.array('d', bytes)
```

where every 8 bytes is interpreted as a double value, making `doubles_sequence` a sequence of doubles, addressable by index. To support a different endianess, you can swap the byte order with `doubles_sequence.byteswap()`.

Comment: How would you go about to extract doubles from the `doubles_sequence`. Say the first double.

Comment: @user2426316: `doubles_sequence[0]` gives you the first value, just like in a list.

Answer (score 5):

You want the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module:

```
>>> d = 1.234
>>> b = struct.pack('d', d)
>>> b
b'X9\xb4\xc8v\xbe\xf3?'
>>> d2, = struct.unpack('d', b)
>>> d2
1.234
```

The `pack` method gives you a `bytes` in Python 3.x, or a `str` in Python 2.x. This type isn't mutable like a Java `byte[]`, and in 2.x it also acts like a sequence of single-character strings, not a sequence of numbers from 0-255. If you need to fix either of those, just convert it to `bytearray`.

Also, note that—in both Java and Python—you probably want to specify an explicit endianness more often than not, especially if you're planning to save the bytes to a file or send them over the network. See [Format Strings](http://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings) for details.

So:

```
>>> b = bytearray(struct.pack('!d', d))
>>> b
bytearray(b'?\xf3\xbev\xc8\xb49X')
>>> b[0]
63
```

Answer (score 0):

This provides a Python implementation of the Java longBitsToDouble and doubleToLongBits operations. Convert the longs to/from byte sequences, eg., as:

```
def doubleToLongBits(d) : 
  bts = struct.pack('d',d)
  return MathLib.bytes2integer(bts)

def longBitsToDouble(x) : 
  bts = MathLib.integer2bytes(x)
  d, = struct.unpack('d',bytes(bts))
  return d
```